# when does UITabbarControll finish loading a view controller?

Tags: ios

I need to layout some views in the view of a view controller  VC which is inside a UITabbarController.

When the view of VC is loaded, its height is the screen height. But after being added to the tabbar controller, its height will be reduced by the height of the tabbar.

I need to do something after the height of the view is adjusted.

I tried to do things inside

```
- (void)loadSubviews
```

of VC. It should be called every time the bounds of the view changed. However, since I used CATransform3D in the VC, it is called multiple times during the animation, even when the bounds of the view is not changed! Strange.

So my question is, how can I tell if the tabbar controller finishes loading its view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass TabBarController and use viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear to detect when the TabBarController has loaded the view